# Pass JSON Object to WCF Service getting NULL message

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf

I want to pass JSON Object to WCF service, 
Here is my service method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
               RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo);

    public string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo)
    {

        return "welcome";
    }
```

Calling from jquery :

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify({ userInfo: data }),
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (result) {
          alert(result);           

      }
  });
```

Here I am getting  NULL message in alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work unless you have issues in your endpoint configuration. check that.
I do not know how you pass your 'data' object.

below code work for me.

```
        var serviceUrl = "Service.svc/InsertUserDetails";
        var data = new Object();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify({ userInfo: data }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                 alert(result);
            }
        });
```